# magento2 update cart title in chekcout after update section cart

Tags: magento2, cart, onepage-checkout

In checkout I have custom ajax request, script to remove a product in checkout. After that update cart section, all works, but I can't update cart qty title "[1 item in cart](https://screenshots.firefox.com/vZA7foZ6osdVWEdA/localhost)".

How can I update it?

Comment: Which template file is generating the "1 item in cart" text you are trying to change?

Comment: @thaddeusmt vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/cart-items.html

Answer (score 2):

I finded solution.

> 1. In my extension created file requirejs-config.js added code:

```
var config = {
    config: { mixins: {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/cart-items': {
            'Vendor_Module/js/view/summary/cart-items': true
        }
    }
    }
};
```

> 2. create mixin file located in Vendor_Module/js/view/summary/cart-items.js and changed function
>      getItemsQty

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
    ],
    function (ko, totals, Component, stepNavigator, quote) {

        'use strict';

        var mixin = {
            getItemsQty: function() {
                var live_qty = parseInt(totals.getItems()().length, 10);
                var qty = this.totals.items_qty;
                if(live_qty != qty){
                    qty = live_qty;
                }
                return parseFloat(qty);
            }
        };

        return function (target) {
            return target.extend(mixin);
        };

    }
);
```

It works for me. Magento 2.1.6